# Android - ZoomableImageView with ViewPager

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, android-viewpager, touch-event

I am having trouble to implement a zoom-and-pan imageview an viewpager. The problem is to allow view pager to page only then completely zoomed out.

I read that I have to play around with onInterceptTouchEvent, and set it to true to have the pager handle the touch event (page) and not the imageView.

Now, how would I let the viewpager know that imageView is zoomed out and not intercept the event? I created an listener that fires inside ImageView's onTouchEvent but obviously it would not work because the event is not even delivered there when intercepted.

Thanks !